# How to set a color for CABasicAnimation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, cabasicanimation

CABasicAnimation has the toValue property which expects an id. But Quartz Core doesn't work with UIColor, it wants a CGColor struct instead. How would I supply a color to a CABasicAnimation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply provide a `CGColor` and typecast it towards an `id`.

```
UIColor *fromColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIColor *toColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
CABasicAnimation *colorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
colorAnimation.duration = 1.0;
colorAnimation.fromValue = (id)fromColor.CGColor;
colorAnimation.toValue = (id)toColor.CGColor;
```

This example fades the background color from red to yellow over 1 second.

Another example as taken directly from [Apple's example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1):

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* colorAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
NSArray* colorValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,  nil];
colorAnim.values = colorValues;
colorAnim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
```

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but a slight correction... UIColor *fromColor = [UIColor redColor]; and UIColor *toColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; (note the asterisks)

Comment: fromValue and toValue support UIColor, passing CGColor causes crash.

Comment: @Andy that is documented where exactly? Apple themselves dont seem to know that - check the example code "Animating Multiple Changes Together" from the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1).

Comment: @Till, actually you are right, it doesn't interpolate UIColors.

Comment: @Till I used it for custom UIColor property which of course crashed, I guess because animation tried to assign CGColorRef to UIColor property.